# res.send() is not sending current response, instead keeps last one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is some of my code that I have in my index.js. Its waiting for the person to visit url.com/proxy and then it loads up my proxy page, which is really just a form which sends back an email and a code. From my MongoDB database, I grab the users order using the code, which contains some information I need (like product and the message they're trying to get). For some reason, it seems like its responding before it gets this information and then holds onto it for the next time the form is submitted.

The newline in my res.send(product + '\n' + message) isnt working either, but thats not a big deal right now.

But.. for example, the first time I fill out the form ill get a blank response. The second time, I'll get the response to whatever I filled in for the first form, and then the third time ill get the second response. I'm fairly new to Web Development, and feel like I'm doing something obviously wrong but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
   app.get('/proxy', function(req,res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/views/proxy.html");
    });

    var message = "";
    var product = "";

    app.post('/getMessage', function(req,res)
    {
        returnMsg(req.body.user.code, req.body.user.email);
        //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.send(product + "\n" + message);
    });

    function returnMsg(code, email){
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
            var cursor = db.collection('Orders').find( { "order_id" : Number(code) })
            cursor.each(function(err, doc){
                assert.equal(err, null);
                if (doc!= null)
                {
                        message = doc["message"];
                        product = doc["product"];
                }
                else {
                        console.log("wtf");
                    // error code here
                }
            });
            console.log(email + " + " + message);
            var document = {
                    "Email" : email,
                    "Message" : message
            }
            db.collection("Users").insertOne(document);
            db.close();
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is not how nodejs works. You must pass to returnMsg() a callback function to execute if db operation suceed. You're trying to do sync programing in node, while this is an asynchonous environment. See this sample and how callback functions are used: https://gist.github.com/fwielstra/1025038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do lots of reading about your asynchronous programming works in node.js.  There are significant design problems with this code:

1. You are using module level variables instead of request-level variables.
2. You are not correctly handling asynchronous responses.

All of this makes a server that simply does not work correctly.  You've found one of the problems already.  Your async response finishes AFTER you send your response so you end up sending the previously saved response not the current one.  In addition, if multiple users are using your server, their responses will tromp on each other.

The core design principle here is first that you need to learn how to program with asynchronous operations.  Any function that uses an asynchronous respons and wants to return that value back to the caller needs to accept a callback and deliver the async value via the callback or return a promise and return the value via a resolved promise.  The caller then needs to use that callback or promise to fetch the async value when it is available and only send the response then.

In addition, all data associated with a request needs to stay "inside" the request handle or the request object - not in any module level or global variables.  That keeps the request from one user from interfering with the requests from another user.

To understand how to return a value from a function with an asynchronous operation in it, see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

---

What ends up happening in your code is this sequence of events:

1. Incoming request for `/getMessage`
2. You call `returnMsg()`
3. returnMsg initiates a connection to the database and then returns
4. Your request handler calls `res.send()` with whatever was previously in the `message` and `product` variables.
5. Then, sometime later, the database connect finishes and you call `db.collection().find()` and then iterate the `cursor`.
   6/ Some time later, the cursor iteration has the first result which you put into your `message` and `product` variables (where those values sit until the next request comes in).

In working out how your code should actually work, there are some things about your logic that are unclear.  You are assigning `message` and `product` inside of `cursor.each()`.  Since `cursor.each()` is a loop that can run many iterations, which value of `message` and `product` do you actually want to use in the `res.send()`?

---

Assuming you want the last `message` and `product` value from your `cursor.each()` loop, you could do this:

```
app.post('/getMessage', function(req, res) {
    returnMsg(req.body.user.code, req.body.user.email, function(err, message, product) {
        if (err) {
            // send some meaningful error response
            res.status(500).end();
        } else {
            res.send(product + "\n" + message);
        }
    });
});

function returnMsg(code, email, callback) {
    let callbackCalled = false;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        var cursor = db.collection('Orders').find({
            "order_id": Number(code)
        });
        var message = "";
        var product = "";

        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                if (!callbackCalled) {
                    callback(err);
                    callbackCalled = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (doc != null) {
                    message = doc["message"];
                    product = doc["product"];
                } else {
                    console.log("wtf");
                    // error code here
                }
            }
        });
        if (message) {
            console.log(email + " + " + message);
            var document = {
                "Email": email,
                "Message": message
            }
            db.collection("Users").insertOne(document);
        }
        db.close();
        if (!callbackCalled) {
            callback(null, message, product);
        }
    });
}
```

Personally, I would use promises and use the promise interface in your database rather than callbacks.

---

This code is still just conceptual because it has other issues you need to deal with such as:

1. Proper error handling is still largely unfinished.
2. You aren't actually waiting for things like the `insert.One()` to finish before proceeding.

Comment: I was expecting only one answer from the cursor, but cursor.each seemed to be the way to get to it, maybe that was wrong. Im reading the link you gave me and checking out what you put into the answer now, i appreciate it.

Comment: @moardee - I added a conceptual code example to my answer.